# ColdFusion 2016 Login failed for SQL Server database

Tags: coldfusion, sql-server-2016

Using ColdFusion 2016 and MS SQL Server Express 2016

I got past the first connection error by turning on TCP/IP and IPALL and setting the port to 1433.

I have SQL Server set to mixed authentication.

ColdFusion Administrator Server: Localhost  Port: 1433

Username and password left blank. In SQL Server, the owner is Administrator, the account used to set up SQL Server and ColdFusion.

Now I can't get past the error:

> Cannot open database "xxx" requested by the login. The login Failed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That error usually has something to do with usernames and passwords,

Comment: Username and password cannot be blank. SQL server will be expecting a login unless you change it. By default on mixed mode it will be the 'sa' account.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new user for the database. 
   Go to the database, then go to security, then add the new user.

Make the new user have admin rights to the database.
Located under: Security>Logins>right click user go to properties
Then click user mapping and make sure they are assigned as a admin for this database.

To limit rights later, you may want to remove admin rights, but try that at first to get it working.